# Logging in to a DoD Windows Secure Host Baseline (SHB) System

Tags: windows, security, deployment

I'm working on a DoD project where I'm upgrading our systems to Windows 10 and Server 2016.  This project calls for a isolated network and the use of the Windows Secure Host Baseline (SHB) that the DoD provides.  I get a build system setup and follow the operations manual to produce a Windows 10 ISO.  I'm currently testing the ISO in a virtual machine, but I have ran into a snag.  No where in the manual does it explain how to log into the system the ISO creates.

During the deployment phase, it asks for a DoD_Admin password.  I successfully give it a password, but when I try to log in with it, it fails.  I have even attempted to join the system to a domain without any luck.

So, how in the world do I log into the system that this setup creates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I missed a step in the documentation that is provided.  The WIM file created by the reference image needs to be added to my build through MDT.  This was throwing me off since it was still creating ISO files with all the deployment wizards.

Comment: How did you finally solve this? I have two stand alones I am trying to setup and it seems no AESD support. I have entered a DOD_admin Password, but that password does not work at the SHB_Admin Password when Windows gets setup. I do not know how to use MDT with this. any help??